# FFMPEG trim long video, fast and accurate way

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, video-processing

I want to trim my a long video using FFMPEG, so I tried:

```
ffmpeg -ss 2 -i in.mp4 -t 72 -c copy out.mp4
```

So the result was not good. the video freeze in the beginning. So I tried without -c copy to re-encode the video, the result was good but it takes a lot of time especially with a large file.

```
ffmpeg -ss 2 -i in.mp4 -t 72 out.mp4
```

So what is the fast way to trim a long video correctly and get a good result?

Comment: the problem is that when doing a trim without encode, ffmpeg will start from the nearest (preceding) keyframe

Comment: Hi, @Islen Boussetta have you find any solution to this issue?

Comment: @VirendraVarma not yet. but I think the last version of FFMPEG 4.1 is faster than the later versions.

Comment: ok please post if you find anything useful thanks.